# MacFusion 2.0.4 on Snow Leopard 10.6.5 with MacFUSE 2.1.5 (beta)

Tags: mac, ssh, macfuse

MacFusion used to work like a charm until I updated to SnowLeopard 10.6.5 and MacFusion 2.0.4. Now I can't mount remote hosts via SSH anymore.

I use the latest version of MacFusion (2.0.4) and MacFUSE 2.1.5.

For earlier versions of MacFusion I had to remove the file "sshnodelay.so" to get it working. The file is no longer included in MacFusion 2.0.4. Does somebody know how to get MacFusion running again?

Cheers

Comment: You may not be interested in this solution, but I gave up on MacFusion and started using [SSHFS GUI](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=sshfs) through MacPorts. MacPorts uses MacFUSE 2.0.3, though, if that's an issue.

Comment: Good idea, thank you! I found another program: http://www.expandrive.com/mac. It works but it's not free and does not offer different features:

Comment: You get functionality similar to ExpanDrive @emempe mentions also from the newest version of Panic's [Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit/) -- the feature is called Transmit Disk.

Comment: Anything on the OPEN side of the Force?